# Wrong addition values

Tags: c++, addition

In this Program in which I'm accepting some values and just adding them. The program is accepting values but showing the wrong addition.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
class Employee
{
    char name[30];
    int id;
    public:
    void Getdata()
    {
        cout<<"Enter Name: ";
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Enter ID: ";
        cin>>id;
    }
    Employee()
    {
    }
    void Putdata()
    {
        cout<<name<<endl;
        cout<<id<<endl;
    }
};
class Salary : public Employee
{
    int sal;
        int basic, hra, da, cla;
    public:
    void set()
    {
        cout<<"Enter Basic Pay: ";
        cin>>basic;
        cout<<"Enter HRA: ";
        cin>>hra;
        cout<<"Enter Da: ";
        cin>>da;
        cout<<"Enter CLA: ";
        cin>>cla;
    }
    Salary() : Employee()
    {
        sal = (basic+hra+da+cla) ;
    }
    void show()
    {
        cout<<"Salary: "<<sal;
    }
};
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    Salary s;
    s.Getdata();
    s.set();
    s.Putdata();
    s.show();
    getch();
}
```

I expected The salary as 13000 but instead getting Salary: 11172 as result.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Not related to your problem, but Salary deriving from Employee seems like a really odd class hierarchy. I mean, in what way is a Salary the same as an employee?

Comment: Also, are you by chance using TurboC++? `void main` and the headers you are using will/should not compile in a standard complaint compiler.

Comment: `sal = (basic+hra+da+cla) ;` calculates an immediate value and sets `sal` to that value. It does not create a relationship, changing any of the operands used after the fact will not retroactively update `sal` to the new value. You'll have to perform the calculation after you've seized the user's inputs.

Comment: In the default constructor of `Salray` you wrote: `sal = (basic+hra+da+cla) ;` but these member variables are not initialized yet!

Comment: `void main` is considered wrong. You should return an integer from main.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` for text, not character arrays.  Character arrays can overflow or waste memory (for small length text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calculating the value of `sal` from un-initialized members in the default constructor: `sal = (basic + hra + da + cla);`. So your program runs an Undefined Behavior.

That is because the constructor runs before any other member. To solve it you should Get the values first then Calculate next:

```
Salary() : Employee(){
//  cout << basic << ", " << hra << ", " << da << ", " <<  cla << endl; // this line proves that hra, basic... are not initialized.
    set(); // assign values before calculate.
    sal = (basic + hra + da + cla);
}
```

- What I recommend is to remove this line from the default constructor: `sal = (basic + hra + da + cla);` and put it in `set`. so `set()` would look like:

  ```
  void set(){
      cout << "Enter Basic Pay: ";
      cin >> basic;
      cout << "Enter HRA: ";
      cin >> hra;
      cout << "Enter Da: ";
      cin >> da;
      cout << "Enter CLA: ";
      cin >> cla;
      sal = (basic + hra + da + cla); // after getting values it is a good place here to process the sal.
  }
  ```
- Another thing to consider is that `main` should return an integer not void. Returning `void` is wrong.
- Also don't use character strings but use `std::string` it is worthy to use:

  ```
  class Employee{
      std::string name;
      int id;
      // ...
  };
  ```
- Also making `Salary` derived from `Employee` is irrelevant:
  Ask yourself: "is a salray an employee?" So the relevant is to achieve a `Has-a` relationship instead of `Is-a` because an employee does have a salary but he is not a salaray.

  ```
  class Salary {
      public:
          Salary() :
              sal{}, basic{}, hra{}, da{}, cla{} {
          }
          void set() {
              std::cout << "Enter Basic Pay: ";
              std::cin >> basic;
              std::cout << "Enter HRA: ";
              std::cin >> hra;
              std::cout << "Enter Da: ";
              std::cin >> da;
              std::cout << "Enter CLA: ";
              std::cin >> cla;
              sal = basic + hra + da + cla;
          }
          void show() {
              std::cout << "Salary: " << sal << std::endl;
          }
      private:
          int sal, basic, hra, da, cla;
  };

  class Employee {
      public:
          Employee() :
              name{}, id{}, sal{} {
          }
          void Getdata() {
              std::cout << "Enter Name: ";
              std::getline(std::cin, name);
              std::cout << "Enter ID: ";
              std::cin >> id;
              sal.set();
          }
          void Putdata() {
              std::cout << name << std::endl;
              std::cout << id << std::endl;
              sal.show();
          }
      private:
          std::string name;
          int id;
          Salary sal;
  };

  int main(){
      Employee emp{};
      emp.Getdata();
      emp.Putdata();

  }
  ```
- NB: The code I wrote doesn't compile on "Turbo C++". Please give up that old and erroneous Compiler and use one if the new sophisticated ones.